# Using the Address function in Openoffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I  want to find the position of the largest value(s) in a row.

I am using this function to get the largest value, MATCH((MAX(start position of row numbers:end position of row numbers),(start position of row numbers, end position of row numbers))), which returns a valid number for the position of my max number in my row.

However, when I try and use the ADDRESS function to translate this integer number into an address, this does not work. I get an Error 502, which means that my syntax is off.

Here is the syntax for my function that I attempt to enter:

ADDRESS(3,(MATCH(MAX(B3:AM3),(B3:AM3)), 1, , , "group2"))

And what it returns in the forumula bar

ADDRESS(3,(MATCH(MAX(B3:AM3),(B3:AM3)),~ 1~ ~~ "group2")), 
with the Err:502 in the Address.

An example of a row I try and search through.

```
sampleA 2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
```

Where sampleA is the label for the row data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should be this.

```
=ADDRESS(3,MATCH(MAX(B3:AM3),B3:AM3), 1, , "group2")
```

There were three problems with your original attempt.

1. The second `B3:AM3` is a range argument for [MATCH](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#MATCH), so it should not have parenthesis as if it was a function call.
2. The extra parentheses surrounding `MATCH` are not allowed.
3. There was an extra `, ,` in the argument list for [ADDRESS](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ADDRESS).

The following does not work either, because of too many parentheses where they don't belong.

```
MATCH((MAX(start position of row numbers:end position of row numbers),(start position of row numbers, end position of row numbers)))
```